# I want execute in bacth via commandline REG IMPORT

Tags: batch, administrator, cmd.exe, import, regedit

When I try to execute this command:

```
REG IMPORT myreg.reg
```

I get `access denied` message, because I'm not administrator. However I don't want to open command line using `run as administrator` in visual way.

How do I just execute this command in a bat file?

Comment: I'm using windows 8 and 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx)

```
runas /savecred /user:administrator "YourBatchFile.bat"
```

where your batch file contains the commands you want to execute in the elevated command prompt. In your case that would be

```
REG IMPORT myreg.reg
```

You will still be prompted for administrator password, but only once. After you have successfully authenticated as admin, the credentials will be saved and you will not be prompted again until you change the admin password.

Comment: Answer me with this problem! [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/1zbtrhs.png[/IMG]

[link]<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=1zbtrhs" target="_blank"><img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/1zbtrhs.png" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Comment: Hm... well, lets skip the politeness subject for now. But you could really give  more details to your question. I have already answered it ,btw